# A cylindrical vessel open at the top

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, steady-state

> A cylindrical vessel open at the top is 20cm high and 10cm in diameter. Circular hole whose cross-sectional area 1 cm² is cut at the centre of the bottom of the vessel water flows from a tube above it into the vessel at the rate 100 cm³/s. Find the height of water in the vessel under steady state.

What is steady state here?

Answer (score 1):

Steady state here refers to the point when the height of water is constant.
In other words, when the rate of water flowing out is equal to the rate of water flowing in.